# Синхронизация файлов разных репозиториев git

Tags: git, github, fork

знакомлюсь с гит системой впервые.

Имеется некий проект с открытым исходным кодом. Проект был скачан и часть кода было модифицировано мою локально и загружено в уже мой репозиторий, код различается в файлах с таким же названием, есть файлы уже созданные мной.

Вопрос, как мне синхронизировать репозиторий основной разработки с моим, но так, чтобы недопустить перезаписи модифицированных файлов? Использовать форк?

Comment: merge или rebase по ситуации